# When was the last time a quaterback from University of Miami (FL) threw a touchdown pass?

Tags: american-football, nfl

As of 22nd October 2023, when was the last time a quarterback from the University of Miami (FL) threw a touchdown pass in the NFL?

Comment: It's not so difficult though. Get the U QB history list -> QB still active -> latest (game) stats. "*The long list of big-time Miami quarterbacks most Canes fans resonate with started with Jim Kelly (1978-1982), and it continued on with many others. Bernie Kosar (1982-1984), Vinnie Testeverde (1982-1986), Craig Erickson (1987-1990), Gino Torretta (1989-1992), Ken Dorsey (1999-2002), Jacory Harris (2008-2011) and Stephen Morris (2010-2013) represented several more of the top signal callers for the Canes*" (FanNation - Sports Illustrated). Latest ones are as easy to find as these...

Comment: This is bіtсh work: https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/909/what-is-the-consensus-on-do-it-for-me-questions

Answer (score 1):

Pro Football Reference is tough to use anymore since it requires a subscription to see all data.

Deducting from the following query, [Miami, FL](https://stathead.com/football/player-span-finder.cgi?request=1&order_by=fantasy_points&year_min=2004&year_max=2009&span_length=1&ccomp%5B1%5D=gt&cval%5B1%5D=1&cstat%5B1%5D=pass_td&college_id=miami%28fl%29&season_positions%5B%5D=qb), the answer is: Vinny Testaverde (2007)